# Is the usage of "information" in infinitive sense idiomatic?

Tags: infinitives, idiomatic-language

> -ation sometimes produce the meaning of infinitive.
>
> For example, conversation means `to converse`.

But information means `facts about a situation, person, event, etc.` ([Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/information))

Is it idiomatic to use information in the sense of `to inform`?

Example:
This is not the right way for information.

Comment: You could not say _This is not the right way for conversation._ so that sort of answers your question - and where does it say that conversation means to converse?

Comment: As a US English speaker: no, the word *information* is never used that way.  It only means "facts".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Information* was originally formed the way you describe and was used in this sense beginning in the 15th century ([source](https://www.etymonline.com/word/information)).  However, in the mid 16th century, it started to refer just to the knowledge delivered rather than the act of delivering it.  Today, *information* is still used in the original sense only in certain [legal contexts](https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/information).

*Explanation* went through the same process, but both senses are still in use.

However, *V-ation* does not mean *to V*.  The suffix *-ation* is actually two suffixes:

- *-ate*, which is used in many Latin loanwords and in this case describes doing or making something into a certain state (e.g., *duplicate*, *separate*, *aggravate*, *instantiate*, *automate*), and
- *-ion*, which makes a noun describing the either the act or the result of doing a verb.

This construction is not the same as the infinitive form of the bare verb.  You can sometimes use an infinitive as a noun the same way you could use *-ation*, but in all the examples I can think of, you could also use the gerund (*-ing*).

These are all very similar, but I think (1) is the most idiomatic in casual use but the others are more acceptable for highly formal use:

1. Automating the factory would cost jobs.
2. To automate the factory would cost jobs.
3. Automation of the factory would cost jobs.